# Ajax post request with Authorization header from .aspx page giving error "Option 405 (Method Not Allowed) "

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web.config-transform, web-config

I have aspx page from where i am sending the jquery ajax post request to my web services. 
i have added the Authorization header to the post call. My code is :-

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        },
        url: " My Web Service URL ",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { HtmlText: data},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

In Web.config  i have added :-

```
 <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="Authorization, Content-Type"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

After sending the request I am getting the response in inspect element (Chrome) :-

Remote Address: " My Remote Address "
Request URL: " My Host URL "
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed

Request Headers view source :-

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,hi;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:" My Host URL "
Origin:test
Referer:/test/MyPage.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36

Response Headers view source :-

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 08 Jul 2014 12:42:10 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC 5 Web Api First I added the customHeader in web.config file for the cross domain, But didn't get the output as expected. So I added the  [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")] to each method in controller and I get the required output. Strange !! But got the output.